# run a software with input file as symbolic link

Tags: shell, command-line, symlink

I have a directory with thousands of files, and I want to run a software multiple times in different directories with the same input files without copy the input in each directory, I have created a symbolic link to each file with the next code

```
ln -s /path/to/bayestraits/*_b.txt /path/to/bayestraits/dependiente_1
```

the directory structure is as follow

```
bayestraits
    dependiente_1
    dependiente_2
    dependiente_3
```

and I want to run the next code in each directory

```
for file in *_b.txt; do BayesTraitsV3 cyanomarkers_2.nex $file < Discrete_Dependent.txt ; done
```

the trouble is that when I run the code, the output file is redirected to bayestraits directory no to dependiente_1 directory

Comment: Is your current working directory one of the `dependiente_?` directories when you run your loop, or are you located in the `bayestraits` directory?  Can you explicitly tell your program where to create its output files with an option?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of symbolic links you could create hard links without the `-s` flag:

```
ln /path/to/bayestraits/*_b.txt /path/to/bayestraits/dependiente_1
```

To overwrite your existing symbolic links without removing them, use the `-f` (force) flag

```
ln -f /path/to/bayestraits/*_b.txt /path/to/bayestraits/dependiente_1
```